# I got this error in codeigniter 4 CRITICAL - 2022-01-23 06:55:09 --> chmod(): Operation not permitted

Tags: php, codeigniter

> CRITICAL - 2022-01-23 06:55:09 --> chmod(): Operation not permitted
> #0 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->errorHandler(2, 'chmod(): Operat...', '/Applications/X...', 136, Array)
> #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tec_hr/system/Cache/Handlers/FileHandler.php(136): chmod('/Applications/X...', 416)
> #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tec_hr/system/Throttle/Throttler.php(147): CodeIgniter\Cache\Handlers\FileHandler->save('throttler_authT...', 1642942509, 60)
> #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tec_hr/app/Controllers/Erp/Auth.php(83): CodeIgniter\Throttle\Throttler->check('auth', 5, 60)
> #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tec_hr/system/CodeIgniter.php(918): App\Controllers\Erp\Auth->login()
> #5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tec_hr/system/CodeIgniter.php(404): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->runController(Object(App\Controllers\Erp\Auth))
> #6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tec_hr/system/CodeIgniter.php(312): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest(NULL, Object(Config\Cache), false)
> #7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tec_hr/index.php(45): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
> #8 {main}

Comment: i can visit the home page of my website and the forget password page also but if i login to inside my website its just stay at the homepage and in log files it throw that error i have given all the permission for the xamp folder and to the project folder